# sending object as XML

Tags: java, rest, jaxb

I have this code in my client application

```
Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget t = c.target("http://localhost:8080/PlayerRest/r/Player");

    Player p = new Player();
    p.setPid(new Integer(954));
    p.setNickname("testForPUT");

    t.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(Entity.entity(p, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
```

This gives me juicy exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class Player, genericType=class Player.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:270)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:655)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:412)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.put(JerseyInvocation.java:306)
    at ClientRest.main(ClientRest.java:20)
```

What could be the problem here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JAXB support

> From version 2.16 onwards, all JAX-B providers are being bundled in a separate module.

Add the jersey-media-jaxb jar in your project or you can add dependency in your pom.xml for the required jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```